# Twitter Bootstrap Validation does not work on tablet

Tags: asp.net, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form with simple username and password, designed in ASP.NET 3.5. I have the "required" attribute for both. They validate okay on desktop but not on tablet and mobile.

I didn't add any device specific code. I use Chrome for Desktop, iPad for tablet and BlackBerry for mobile to test. I also have BrowserStack for other devices.

Comment: Seeing that this is an old question, it was likely resolved. If you realized the solution, please answer your own question, else post some code here for further help with it. Without any code sample, it is unlikely to get a solution.

Comment: Actually, I ended up deleting the code and using javascript validation. So, how do I close this question? Should I just delete it or "answer my question"?

Comment: it's always encouraged to answer your own question if the answer is known. thanks for doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap requires .NET 4.0 or above to use native validation like `email validation` where you can use `TextBox` properties like `type="email"`. I ended up using `javascript validation` instead.